# Play song in Notification

Tags: swift, push-notification, swift3, apple-push-notifications

I want to play a song. When a notification comes. My code is working fine when the app is foreground mode. I want to play a song when the app is in background mode. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Add custom sound to your local notification

**Swift 3.0**

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    var state: UIApplicationState = application.applicationState
    if state == .active {
        var soundID: SystemSoundID
        var mainBundle: CFBundleRef = CFBundleGetMainBundle()
        var ref: CFURLRef? = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, ("mySoundName.wav" as? CFString), nil, nil)
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(ref, soundID)
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)
    }
    else {
        // Push Notification received in the background
    }
}
```

For Push notification
Add this to payload..

```
{
 aps =
 {
    alert = "message";
    sound = "pushSound.caf";//this file will have to your bundle
   };
}
```

Comment: added the 3.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make couple of changes in plist file.

1.) Set Required background mode to App plays audio.

2.) Set Application does not run in background to YES

**Code**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
var state: UIApplicationState = application.applicationState
if state == .active {
    print("User Info : \(userInfo.description)")
    print("User Info Alert Message : \(userInfo["aps"]["alert"])")
    var messageString: String? = "\((userInfo["aps"] as? String)?["alert"] as? String)"
    var playSoundOnAlert: String? = "\((userInfo["aps"] as? String)?["sound"] as? String)"
    var url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(Bundle.main.resourcePath)/\(playSoundOnAlert)")
    var error: Error?
    audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0
    audioPlayer.play()
}
}
```