# Change notification behavior swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, swift5

I need to call a notification so that the phone vibrates and rings for several minutes at a certain point in time, planned for earlier.

To send a notification, I use UNNotificationRequest. after searching, I realized that you can only change .sound, having muted the sound for 30 seconds. Which does not fit.

I thought to make several notifications at intervals of a second, but there is a limit on the number of notifications (64 pieces), and this is not enough. Then I tried to cause vibration with

```
 func application (_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if application.applicationState == .background {
        for _ in 1 ... 30 {
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
            sleep(1)
        }
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }
 }
```

But the problem is that I do not know, how to call this function at a certain point in time, and even if the application is killed. 
+ There is a problem with the fact that when you open the application, the vibration does not pass. 
+ performFetch more than anything else for network requests.

**Question**: **I need to attract the user's attention with vibration + melody (if the mode allows it) + notification.** **How can this be done, and in which direction should I continue to dig?**

Maybe all the same I somehow can wake the application up in time and start the vibration + melody. A notification will arrive from the system itself.

**UPD 1:** from the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43232737/13642906

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) { }
```

don`t work on ios10  and above.

Now (ios 10 and above) use

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) { }
```

but it`s method don`t call when not called when local notification arrives. **Maybe, am I doing something wrong?**

**Is it possible to do what I want?**

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43224858/play-song-in-notification

Comment: @nivritgupta Thank you for responding. Unfortunately, the answer is to push, but I need local notifications.